# Saving randomly generated numbers to compare

Tags: c#, comparison, storage

```
private void chanceCard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ccards = new ChanceCard();
    MessageBox.Show("Chance Card: " + ccards.ChanceCardNumber());
    ccards = new ChanceCard();
    MessageBox.Show("Opponent's Chance Card: " + ccards.ChanceCardNumber());
```

I am creating a top trumps game in C# and I'm new to GUI programming. Basically I want to know how to generate two random chance cards (as shown above) and store them, so I can then compare them, so the first chance card is assigned to say `int yourChanceCard` and the second is `int pcChanceCard` so I can then compare them later. So:

```
if yourChanceCard > pcChanceCard
{
    blahblahblah
}
else
    Blah
```

Comment: the shortcut is `ctrl+k` over highlighted text

Comment: what generates the random card? the `new ChanceCard()`? or the `ccards.ChanceCardNumber()` ? and if the latter, what does that return?

Answer (score 0):

if your main class has two member variables like so:

```
class MyProgram  
{  
    ChanceCard mine;  
    ChanceCard opponent;  
    //getters / setters
}
```

You can do something like this:

```
private void chanceCard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mine = new ChanceCard();
    MessageBox.Show("Chance Card: " + mine.ChanceCardNumber());
    opponent = new ChanceCard();
    MessageBox.Show("Opponent's Chance Card: " + opponent.ChanceCardNumber());  
}
```

and finally

```
if mine > opponent
{
    blahblahblah
}
else
    Blah
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. I've put my getters and setters in the Chance Card class, now I'm back in the chanceCard_click and when I try and type "mine" it says "the name 'mine' does not exist in current context"

Comment: One sec, think i've figured out what I did wrong, accidently stated them in the chance card instead of main!

Comment: However now I am implementing my if statement and it says that the operator > cannot be applied to operands of type chancecard

Comment: As a side note, you probably dont want a bunch of unrelated members cluttering up main.

Comment: @user2326995 Consider making `ChanceCard` implement `IComparable` or `IEqualityComparer`